# Multiple File Tables MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

I'm running MariaDB (10.0.2-MariaDB) on CentOS 6.4 and would like to use MariaDB's CONNECT-Engine to read from some log files. Since the log files are way to big I recreated the error with two CSV files consisting of one line each.

```
MariaDB [jedi]> create table test1 ( a char(10), b char(10) ) engine=CONNECT table_type=CSV file_name='/tmp/test1.csv' sep_char=';' compress=0 multiple=0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [jedi]> create table test2 ( a char(10), b char(10) ) engine=CONNECT table_type=CSV file_name='/tmp/test2.csv' sep_char=';' compress=0 multiple=0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [jedi]> select * from test1;
+------+------+
| a    | b    |
+------+------+
| test | bla  |
+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [jedi]> select * from test2;
+-------+------+
| a     | b    |
+-------+------+
| test2 | blub |
+-------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now the interesting feature would be to merge these files into one table, which should be possible (says https://kb.askmonty.org/en/connect-table-types-data-files/#multiple-file-tables).

But if I do it:

```
MariaDB [jedi]> create table test_all ( a char(10), b char(10) ) engine=CONNECT table_type=CSV file_name='/tmp/test*.csv' sep_char=';' compress=0 multiple=1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [jedi]> select * from test_all;
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

Does anyone know an explanation? Never mind the "compress=0", I also tested reading from gzipped files, which works like a charme... until you try to read from two files into one table.

Thanks,
Jens

Comment: Are the log files active?  That is, are they being updated at the time you are trying to pull data from them?

Comment: No, they are just two very simple files which are not accessed by anyone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in MariaDB 10.0.2 which is fixed in 10.0.3 (the [corresponding ticket](https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-4524) says 10.0.4 but the error does not happen anymore with 10.0.3).